# little problem with discord 1.0.1 make bot leave

Tags: discord.py

currently i have this

```
@client.command()
async def comrade(ctx, amountt=30):
    if not ctx.message.author.voice:
        await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel")
        return
    
    else:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel

    vc = await channel.connect()
    vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('songs.mp3'))
```

but i can't figure out how to make the bot leave if it's already connected to the voice channel

i also tried this but it dosen't work:

```
def is_connected(ctx):
    voice_client = get(ctx.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    return voice_client and voice_client.is_connected()
```

Comment: wait, are you really using `discord.py` 1.0.1?

Comment: no the tag was discord.py i'm using discord.py 1.5.1, discord library it's 1.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong in your code, but the easiest way to leave a channel is the next one:

```py
async def leave(ctx):
    voice = ctx.voice_client # You can only have one vc client per guild, that's why this works
    if voice is None:
        # The bot is not in a voice channel
        return await ctx.send("Bot is not in a voice channel") 

    # Leaving the channel
    await voice.disconnect()
```

#### Reference:

- [`Context.voice_client`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context%20voice#discord.ext.commands.Context.voice_client)
- [`VoiceProtocol.disconnect`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceProtocol.disconnect)